# how split a string from comma(,) or newlines ot tab

Tags: python, regex

```
[s.strip() for s in data_string.splitlines()] 

text = "aaa bbb ccc, dddeee abc \n ram and shyam \t"
```

i want a code like

```
['aaa bbb ccc','dddeee abc','ram and shyam']
```

Comment: Use `re.split(r'[,\t\r\n]+', text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `re.split` after first trimming whitespace from the input:

```py
text = "aaa bbb ccc, dddeee abc \n ram and shyam \t"
parts = re.split(r'[ ]*[,\t\n][ ]*', text.strip())
print(parts)  # ['aaa bbb ccc', 'dddeee abc', 'ram and shyam']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `None` filter like:

```py
text = "aaa bbb ccc, dddeee abc \n ram and shyam \t" 
arr = filter(None, re.split(r'[,\t\n]+', text))
print [s.strip() for s in arr]
```

**Output:**

```
['aaa bbb ccc', 'dddeee abc', 'ram and shyam']
```